# Double render error when trying to auto sign in and redirect user into a specific path after registration in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi I am getting a double redirection here

What I've been trying to accomplish is to auto sign in the user and redirect the user into a specific path, not in the root path.

In my registrations_controller.rb

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]
    @valid = @user.save
    if @valid
      sign_up
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end

  def sign_up
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
```

In my application_controller.rb

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.admin? or resource.super_admin?
      admin_index_path      
    else
      if mobile_device?
        page_path("backgroundinfo")
      else
        page_path("howto")
      end
    end
  end

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    page_path("howto")
  end
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

PS: Removing the `respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` is still redirecting the user to the `root_path` not in the `page_path` maybe because the controller action is in registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double render error happens when you try to render two templates from the same request.

Your `sign_up` method attempts to respond with a `respond_with` block, and after that your `create` method attempts to make another response from the `respond_to` block. Here is the issue:

```
if @valid
  sign_up
end
```

This calls your `sign_up` method which attempts to render a response. After that happens, the following block tries to render another template:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render layout: false }
end
```

Your execution path attempts two `render` calls, which gets you a double render error.

Your code should look like something along these lines:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        # sign in user here and render response for success
        format.js  { #handle js }
        format.html { #handle html }
      else
        # user was not saved
        format.js  { #handle error }
        format.html { #handle error }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: How can I sign in the user and make the page redirect to `page_path` after sign up process?

Comment: Devise has a method to sign the user. I never use Devise as it wastse more time than it saves, but it has a method to sign in the user. It should be available in the documentation. Take a glance.

Comment: Yes the method is `sign_in(resource)` but the thing is that it's still going to the `root_path` though I override the `after_sign_in_path`

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and bypassed it by overriding Devise::SessionsController, like so:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    #yield resource if block_given?
    #respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))


    # The rest of your code

    # your redirect
         redirect_to '/'

end
```

I'm unsure as to whether this has any negative side affects, but it appears to work fine, and also stops it from appending user sign-in data to the URL.